# How to share project directories into home directory of members

Tags: shared-folders

I've a requirement that when a user logs in, they should see the shared directories of the projects they are a part of, in the user home. They should not see any other project directory. Users should have read/write access.

For example, say there are three users u1, u2 and u3 and two projects p1, p2. u1 is a part of p1, u2 is a part of p2 but u3 has access to both p1 and p2. Once they login, their home directory should look like below.

- U1 home -> p1
- U2 home -> p2
- U3 home -> p1, p2

In my case, there will be 100s of users and projects. Less than 5% of the users are being a member of multiple projects.

Comment: 1. Set up groups 2. Assign file permissions based on group 3. Add user to groups 4. Create symlinks in user homes

Comment: @Panki Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting the answer posted by @panki in the comments.

1. Set up groups
2. Assign file permissions based on group
3. Add user to groups
4. Create symlinks in user homes