# How to share project directories into SFTP home directory of members

Tags: mount, symlink, sftp, shared-folders, file-sharing

I've a requirement that when a user logs in, they should see the shared directories of the projects they are a part of, in the user's SFTP home. They should not see any other project directory. Users should have read/write access.

For example, say there are three users u1, u2 and u3 and two projects p1, p2. u1 is a part of p1, u2 is a part of p2 but u3 has access to both p1 and p2. Once they login, their home directory should look like below.

- U1 home -> p1
- U2 home -> p2
- U3 home -> p1, p2

In my case, there will be 100s of users and projects. Less than 5% of the users are being a member of multiple projects.

I tried the symlink solution suggested in [How to share project directories into home directory of members](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752638/how-to-share-project-directories-into-home-directory-of-members)

1. Set up groups
2. Assign file permissions based on group
3. Add user to groups
4. Create symlinks in user homes

But it does not work here since I've used `ChrootDirectory` to have user specific home in sshd_config.

Also, I've tried `mount --bind`. But it did not work when multiple mounts are created to the same project directory. Once a new mount is created, the old files in the project directory gets vanished.

Comment: You need to bind mount the same directory to multiple places, not the other way around!